# Compare 2 columns, and return a certain value if it's true

Tags: excel

I want to compare 2 columns, and if matching cells are true, I want the formula to return me the associated value of A2:A4. Here is an example :

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `IF(B2=F2, A2, "NOT FOUND")`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F2,B:B,0)),"Not found")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Index/Match`, `XLOOKUP()`, `FILTER()` will give you desired result. If you are in `Excel-O365` then I would recommend `XLOOKUP()`. Try below-

```
=XLOOKUP(E2:E4,B2:B4,A2:A4,"Not Found")
```

For table object try-

```
=XLOOKUP(E2:E4,Table1[Name_Address],Table1[ID],"Not Found")
```

More about [XLOOKUP](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-xlookup-function) to exceljet.net

[image]